# R Error in contrib.url(repos, "Source) upon trying to install a package, without specifying the repo

Tags: r, installation

Hi all I am working in R trying to run some code using RMarkdown, this is the snippet of code that seems to be giving me a problem.

```
install.packages("car")
install.packages("bestNormalize")
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(leaps)
library(MASS)
library(car)
library(plyr)
library(alr4)
```

Its pretty standard stuff. I receive the following error when trying to run the code.

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source"):trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror Calls:
 <Anonymous> ... withVisible 
-> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url Execution halted
```

I recently bought a new laptop and installed R. In my old laptop when I specified an install("package_name") I never received this error. Is there a reason why this is occurring? I have already seen proposed solutions to be specifying the repo in the following way:

```
install.packages("car", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

I am not content with this solution however as I would not like to specify the repos every time I try to install a package. I thought about perhaps finding some way to set the mirror to a default one but have no idea if this can be done. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I did the following: I located and opened my .RProfile by running the command:

```
file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile"))
```

Then I navigated to https://cran.r-project.org and found the mirror that was closest to my location. Then in the .Rprofile I wrote the following command in order to have R studio acknowledge my preference when opened

```
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="https:theclosest_mirror_to_yourlocation.com")))
```

Saving this into the .Rprofile and running the initial code shows that it was successful.