# Libraries fail to load

Tags: r, shared-libraries

I've already tried everything I've come across on Stack overflow: uninstalling libraries and RStudio, reinstalling them, downloading R tools, and even this solution from another post:

[R Error in contrib.url(repos, "Source) upon trying to install a package, without specifying the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876915/r-error-in-contrib-urlrepos-source-upon-trying-to-install-a-package-without)

But to no avail. I still keep getting this same message when opening any library I have installed (example with readr), which prevents me from working with them:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘readr’ was built under R version 4.2.3
```

Any ideas? I'm desperate.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `libPaths()`?

Comment: What version of R are you using? The error message states that the rlang dependency requires version 1.1.0 or greater to run the readr library - but you seem to have version 1.0.6. The readr library loaded without issue on my end - I have just checked the rlang description for my version of R (4.2.3) and the version is 1.1.0.

Comment: Your description of what you have tried doesn't include updating the installed packages (and it also doesn't include updating R).

Comment: Restart R. Run `install.packages("rlang")` first thing. Make sure that works without error. If it does, then run `install.packages("readr")`